# C++ program that connects to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Right now this is purely hypothetical (I hope this doesn't cause the question to be closed. This question has the potential to help visitors and I want to do this.) because I haven't used a true programming language like C++ in almost two years. However, I'm getting restarted with C++ and I've always been a person to jump straight into projects.

I have my website, www.gracepensacola.com, and I'm working on designing some forms to receive user information. The information will be stored in our MySQL database.

I need my C++ program to connect to the database, retrieve the required information, and then display it using the QT library. (I'm just starting with C++ GUI).

I have no clue about the steps I have to take to make this. I haven't seen anything on C++ contacting MySQL.

Comment: just so you know, any c++ program will be running on the server unless it's a browser plugin or something. Is the 'required information' part of a html page or somewhere else?

Comment: I didn't realize it has to run on the server. I was hoping that I could have a standalone program that did that for me. When I said 'required information' I meant specified. It would be the name, age, phone, address, etc.

Comment: okay, the easiest way that I know of to do that is by using js and php. i'll post more info in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as you'll get to mysql and c++:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

And just to make sure your on the same page as everyone else: C/C++ programs run on the server. That means you can't get information from someone viewing the window with a c++ program ( at least, not very easily ).

If you'd like to get information from a browser page, you'd connect to mysql using 
javascript along with php. I think this is what you'll have to end up doing if it has anything to do with people visiting your site on a browser. If you've learned c/c++, than javascript and php shouldn't be very hard for you to learn.

You would start my retrieving the data you need with javascript, like this:

```
// trivial way to get values in javascript
var userName = document.getElementById( "name" ).innerHTML;
var userAddr = document.getElementById( "address" ).innerHTML;
var userPhne = document.getElementById( "phoneNumber" ).innerHTML;
```

You would then send the data to a php script, like this:

```
// javascript with a jquery library
$.post( "getData.php", { uName : userName, uAddr : userAddr } );
```

And you'd receive those values in a php script:

```
<?php
    $uName = $_POST[ "uName" ]; // now $uName = userName from the browser page
    $uAddr = $_POST[ "uAddr" ];
    // mysql stuff goes here
?>
```

If you prefer javascript, you can also use javascript for a server side script that connects to mysql. I believe you would do that just like I did above, except you'd call a .js file.
You can get more info on these links:

Using PHP

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Using javascript, with node.js

https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native

There's an easy way to receive data into a c++ program using php as well. Following the last php/javascript example:

```
<?php
    $uName = $_POST[ "uName" ]; // now $uName = userName from the browser page
    $uAddr = $_POST[ "uAddr" ];

    shell_exec( "cProgram.exe " . $uName . " " . $uAddr )
?>
```

This will pass the arguments to a c/c++ program that has the following entry point:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){

    // argv[ 0 ] contains program name
    // argv[ 1 ] contains uName
    // argv[ 2 ] contains uAddr

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it still possible to display the results using C++? My goal of this was to increase my understanding and efficiency of C++. Would it be easier to to save the information into a text file and make my program read the file and display the information?

Comment: yes, you can use php to initiate a c++ program and pass along the data as arguments of the program. I'll post more info about that in my answer

Comment: This is showing my ignorance, but will the C++ application still have to be on the server or can PHP initialize a program on the hosts computer? I know that it is possible to read and write and I know that flvs.net has something that downloads a java file then runs the script.

Comment: there's not a way for any scripting language to start a non-script program, c++ or otherwise, on a remote computer. I think mostly because it presents too many security issues.

Comment: Okay. That does make sense. I'll just need to create a separate page for log in for the administrators. I can find plenty of authentication tutorials online. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

If you never done that before, the first (obvious) step is to read tutorials [like this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html)

then read about Qt way to connect databases [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-connecting.html)